# Cuting an URL with JS or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsing

Hello guys is it possible to throw away the first part of an url

```
var mydir = $("script[src$='jquery_main.js']").attr('src').slice(0, -14);

http://127.0.0.1:9081/Mgr/resources/ui/skins/default/js/main/
```

im trying to remove this part "http://127.0.0.1:9081/Mgr/" but without indexOf. is it possible to cut the url after the third /  to get just this part `/resources/ui/skins/default/js/main/`

Comment: `'http://127.0.0.1:9081/Mgr/resources/ui/skins/default/js/main/'.split('/').splice(4).join('/')` or `'http://127.0.0.1:9081/Mgr/resources/ui/skins/default/js/main/'.split('/').slice(4).join('/')`

Comment: you can use location.href.slice(25)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you don't want to use `indexOf`, you can try this as well

```
var cutURL = "/" + "http://127.0.0.1:9081/Mgr/resources/ui/skins/default/js/main/".split(/\/+/).splice(3).join("/");
```

**DEMO**

```js
    var url = "http://127.0.0.1:9081/Mgr/resources/ui/skins/default/js/main/";
    var cutURL = "/" + url.split(/\/+/).splice(3).join("/");
    alert(cutURL);
```

Comment: The Mgr folder is not static and can be renamed so i cant use indexOf with "Mgr" , thnaks for ur help :)